# User WPF control within browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a web-browser control in WPF screen and some other controls like (general structure).

```
<WPF Window>
    <Web Browser>
    </Web Browser>
    <Other Control>
    </Other Control>
</WPF Window>
```

I want to display notification pop up (html, not WPF one) but it should come over Other Control. By default it just come above it because I used it inside Web Browser control as it is not supported by Other Control. Other Control is WPF control that occupies most of the screen. How to position pop up to display it on Other Control?